# Sequelize loading in initial data

Tags: mysql, database, migration, sequelize.js, seeding

I need to load data into a DB using Sequelize on first application load. The initial excel data was given in the following format:

**Car group fields**: title | group_code

**Car group data**:
('Mercedes','M'),
('Volkswagen','VW');

**Car Fields**:  car_code | owner | group_code

**Car data**:
('11-1135','Fred','M'),
('11-1146','Bob','VW');

--

Ideally what I want to end up with in the DB is the following:

Car group fields: group_id | title | group_code

Car group data:
(1, 'Mercedes','M'),
(2, 'Volkswagen','VW');

Car Fields:  car_id | car_code | owner | group_id (refers to the group id created above)

Car data:
(1, '11-1135','Fred', 1),
(2, '11-1146','Bob', 2);

--

What is the best approach to doing this in Sequelize? In SQL I did the following to get around this problem:

1- Converted my Excel file into a bunch of SQL statements

2- Created the following script using those statements (and then i added my own code to fill in the group_id):

```
CREATE TABLE CarGroup(
    group_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    group_code   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
    CONSTRAINT UN_car_group_code UNIQUE (group_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO CarGroup(title,group_code) VALUES ('Mercedes','M');
INSERT INTO CarGroup(title,group_code) VALUES ('Volkswagen','VW');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Car(
  car_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  car_code VARCHAR(10),
  owner VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  group_id SMALLINT, -- populated after insert 
  group_code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, -- deleted after insert

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT `UN_car_code` UNIQUE (`car_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_car_group_id` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `CarGroup` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO Car(car_code,owner,group_code) VALUES ('11-1135','Fred','M');
INSERT INTO Car(car_code,owner,group_code) VALUES ('11-1146','Bob','VW');

-- GENERATE GROUP ID'S BASED ON GROUP CODE AND DROP GROUP CODE COLUMN --
update Car INNER JOIN CarGroup ON Car.group_code = CarGroup.group_code
    SET Car.group_id = CarGroup.group_id;
alter table Car drop column group_code
```

I can't see how the above can be achieved by using migrations and seeding as I need to create the model then do seeding and then run the alteration. Is it easier to just run plain SQL statements in Sequelize in this case? Or should I just use the data as it is and link the two tables as a foreign key via the group_code (which is a string - not best performance in comparison to plain INT id).

Any direction on this is muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach but since no one answered, but i have decided to do the following:

- Create two tables, OriginalCars and Cars. OriginalCars has the original fields that the excel file has (i.e.  car_code). The Cars table has the car_id and other fields.
- Create the models
- Sync the models
- Check manually if there is any data in the tables, if not then populate the ***originalCars*** table with data. I then do an innerjoin of the OriginalCars with the group table, the resulting data is parsed and added to the Car table with car_id.
- Delete the original table as its no longer needed

Feels a tad hacky but it only has to do this on initial load of the App to populate the initial data.